# Stop all Pods in a StatefulSet before scaling it up or down

Tags: docker, kubernetes, discord

My team is currently working on migrating a Discord chat bot to Kubernetes. We plan on using a **StatefulSet** for the main bot service, as each [Shard](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sharding) (pod) should only have a single connection to the [Gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway). Whenever a shard connects to said Gateway, it tells it its ID (in our case the pod's ordinal index) and **how many shards we are running in total** (the amount of replicas in the StatefulSet).

Having to tell the gateway the total number of shards means that in order to scale our StatefulSet up or down **we'd have to stop all pods in that StatefulSet before starting new ones with the updated value**.

How can I achieve that? Preferrably through configuration so I don't have to run a special command each time.

Comment: Can you check the relevant answers and see if this can be closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this is,
Firstly get the YAML configuration of StatefulSets by running the below command and save it in a file:

```
kubectl get statefulset NAME -o yaml > sts.yaml
```

And then delete the StatefulSets by running the below command:

```
kubectl delete -f sts.yaml
```

And Finally, again create the StatefulSets by using the same configuration file which you got in the first step.

```
kubectl apply -f sts.yaml
```

I hope this answers your query to only delete the StatefulSets and to create the new StatefulSets as well.

Answer (score 15):

Try `kubectl rollout restart sts <sts name>` command. It'll restart the pods one by one in a RollingUpdate way.

Scale down the sts
`kubectl scale --replicas=0 sts <sts name>`

Scale up the sts
`kubectl scale --replicas=<number of replicas> sts <sts name>`

Comment: I think I didn't mention that in the original question, sorry: I need to stop all pods before starting them again, because the gateway doesn't let you connect extra shards if there are connections still open with the old shard count value.

Comment: Still not what I was asking about. I need a way to automate stopping all pods before an update/scaling occurs, due to the way the service interacts with the gateway

Comment: I think it does answer: `scale --replicas=0` will stop all your pods, then `scale --replicas=N` will start them all with the new desired pod number. @hariK may want to delete the first part of the answer using `restart` which indeed does not do what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Before any `kubectl scale`, since you need [more control on your nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#maintenance-on-a-node), you might consider a [`kubectl drain`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#drain) first

> When you are ready to put the node back into service, use kubectl uncordon, which will make the node schedulable again.

By draining the node where your pods are maanged, you would stop all pods, with the opportunity to [scale the statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/scale-stateful-set/#scaling-statefulsets) with the new value.

---

See also "[How to Delete Pods from a Kubernetes Node](http://How%20to%20Delete%20Pods%20from%20a%20Kubernetes%20Node)" by **[Keilan Jackson](https://github.com/krjackso)**

Start at least with `kubectl cordon <nodename>` to mark the node as unschedulable.

> If your pods are controlled by a StatefulSet, first make sure that the pod that will be deleted can be safely deleted.
>   How you do this depends on the pod and your application’s tolerance for one of the stateful pods to become temporarily unavailable.
>
> For example you might want to demote a MySQL or Redis writer to just a read-only slave, update and release application code to no longer reference the pod in question temporarily, or scale up the ReplicaSet first to handle the extra traffic that may be caused by one pod being unavailable.
>
> Once this is done, delete the pod and wait for its replacement to appear on another node.

Comment: I need to stop the pods in that StatefulSet only, not a whole node

Comment: @PedroFracassi Any chance to have those statefulsets pods isolated in a dedicate node? Because force deleting a pod managed by a Statefulset seems dangerous (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/)